# Can OData be made to return CSV or URL?

Tags: json, rest, csv, odata

I'm new to OData so I'm sorry if this is a bad question, but I fail to find an answer.

I have a bunch of OData tables, and I would like to provide an option for the user to get the data as a CSV-file.

Now I know OData only supports Atom and JSON, but is there any way to make it return a filestream, or a URL?

I was thinking a URL could direct to a REST-service (not OData) that simply returns a filestream, if filestream directly from OData is impossible.

Any thoughts or ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totaly sure why you want to use oData. But oData essentially means to publish any kind of data in JSON/atom standard format - not CSV.

If you have controll over your oData source you could modify an oData Producer to output CSV filestreams instead of JSON/atom files.(But you wouldn't have a real oData feed anymore)
You could also set up any oData Consumer (you can find those at [odata.org](http://www.odata.org/ecosystem/)) to read your oData source and display it as CSV.

If you choose a server side solution(PHP/JSP/ASP etc.) it should be rather simple to loop through the results of a request and add seperators inbetween.

Comment: You're right, unfortunately, it's not up to me to chose OData or something else.  
  How would one make a producer to return filestreams? Could that be done without violating the OData specification? I do have access to the producers/providers but I don't want to weaken the protocol implementation.  
  Yes, the loop-through is definetly an option, but I would prefer a fix within the providers, if possible.

Comment: as I said, this wouldn't be an OData provider anymore.(so you are definitely violating the specifications by changing the output to csv) 

In fact your benefit from modifying a OData Producer could be the reuse of the whole backend part (especially the whole uri request language and db connection).

How to modify such a producer depends massively on the library you are using. (I guess this will be a lot of work todo, while looping through the result of a standard producer would be the quick and dirty way)

Comment: I ended up doing the easy non-violoating solution. A converter that transforms the OData objects to CSV-formatted string, and then a REST-service that retrurns the String as a filestream. 
Thanks for the advice!

Comment: That's not really true. There's nothing specifically JSON-centric for OData. OData is a great way of applying standardized filters and formatting on queryable data, and there's definitely a use case for exporting to CSV.

Comment: While your oData Producer may offer additional formats (csv could be such a format), at least one of the two default formsts json/atom must be supported. See oData standard section 6.6 for reference.